# Get domain name in url

Tags: javascript

I want to use regex and get domain name (only [a-z]) from url.

For example:

https://google.com `//Result: google`

https://google22.com `//Result: google`

https://images.google.com `//Result: google`

https://images23.google.com `//Result: google`

https://images22.google33.com `//Result: google`

I try with my `regex` function

Here my javascript function at below

```
 const getHostnameFromRegex = (url) => {
    const matches = url.match('/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?((.*)+)\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i');
    return matches && matches[1];
 }
```

At my function not working properly. Could you please help me about this regex function?

Comment: should it work on `https://images.google.co.uk` ?

Comment: no. only com, net, org, xyz, site, live something like this

Comment: Then do a `new URL(url).hostname.split('.')` get the second from last and clean it up from unwanted chars and see what remains.

Comment: https://w3collective.com/get-domain-name-url-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Michael was answer. its work after i change it with const function.

Here working code. Thank you Michael.

```js
const getHostnameFromRegex = (url) => {
    const host = new URL(url).host;
    const dots = host.split('.');
    return dots.at(-2).replace(/\d/g, '');
}

console.log(getHostnameFromRegex('https://google.com'));
console.log(getHostnameFromRegex('https://google22.com'));
console.log(getHostnameFromRegex('https://image22.google22.com'));
```